# How to use eventemitter3 in Vite?

Tags: vite, eventemitter

I migrated from CRA to Vite. And shame on Facebook for CRA and blessings for the Vite team. Because my build time dropped from more than a minute, to less than a second. What a change.

Everything works great.

However, since we should [use](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3#usage) `require` to use `eventemitter3`, I see this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I can't find the solution here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `import` instead of `require()`:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3' // 

const emitter = new EventEmitter()
const onMyEvent = () => console.log('my-event')
emitter.on('my-event', onMyEvent)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-eventemitter3?file=src%2Fevent-bus.js)